# Richtextbox not showing entire string vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, richtextbox

My richtextbox isn't showing the full length of a string (and I don't know why!). I have a richtextbox in which I'm showing an array of bytes and the ascii encoding of those bytes like so;

```
    Dim rt1 As String
    Dim rt2 As String

    Dim num1 As Integer = filedata.headerBytes.GetLength(0) - 1 - 4
    For i = 0 To num1 Step 4
        Dim temp1 As String = ""
        Dim temp2 As String = ""
        Dim b1(3) As Byte
        Dim b2(3) As Byte
        For j = 0 To 3
            b1(j) = filedata.headerBytes(i + j)
            b2(j) = filedata.rawInput(i + j)
            temp1 = temp1 & filedata.headerBytes(i + j) & " "
            temp2 = temp2 & filedata.rawInput(i + j) & " "
        Next
        rt1 = rt1 & (temp1 & "    " & System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b1.ToArray) & Chr(13))
        rt2 = rt2 & (temp2 & "    " & System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b2.ToArray) & Chr(13))
    Next
    RichTextBox1.Text = rt1
    RichTextBox2.Text = rt2
```

I've tried changing rt1 and rt2 to string builders (and modifying the code to take this into account) but I'm having the same issue. Here's a sample of the string that gets created;

```
"82 73 70 70     RIFF" & vbCr & "178 141 49 0     ??1 " & vbCr & "87 65 86 69     WAVE" & vbCr & "102 109 116 32     fmt " & vbCr &...
```

And here's where the richtextbox shows to;

```
"82 73 70 70     RIFF" & vbLf & "178 141 49 0     ??1"
```

I've never run into this kind of problem in the passed, any ideas?

Comment: This happens because your input contains a byte with value 0. This byte is added to your string but a byte with value 0 is considered as the end of the string by the richtextbox.

Comment: @Steve That was the problem, thanks! Put that in an answer so I can mark this answered please! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your input contains a byte with value 0.
This byte is added to your arrays and then converted to a string.
But a byte with a value of 0 is considered as the end of the string by the RichTextbox.

The only possible workaround that I can imagine is to check for the zero value and convert it to something that you can display.